# Windows Installer Setup

Tags: windows, installation, admin

I'm a novice in setup configuration with VS2010 but my goal is to install my c# application for all the users of a computer (admin or standard user in Windows).
Actually, I succeed to install the application on the admin session, I checked the "for all users" button, but when I log in with a standard user and launch the application, it tries to re-install the application from the setup source (on an external network).

What can I do to install definitely the application on all sessions of the computer? regardless of the type of session

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a per-machine install you need to install the application in Program Files folder. The setup restarts in your case probably because o part of the resources are missing, it is the self-healing mechanism built in that triggers the setup.

Comment: ok thx! i will copy the setup items on the Program Files folder, but do you have a tutorial for a batch/autorun file which could do this for all versions of Windows?

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with the package created by VS?